# faulty Java string concatenation

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Hello i'm writing a program and I have one single error. I can't figure out why this line of code won't work in java.

System.out.println("y = " + String(first.getSlope())+"x + " + String(first.getYIntercept())));

Comment: Hi, can you please paste the console output and the error that you get when executing the code?

Comment: There is no function called `String(…)`

Answer (score 1):

As the first value is a string, the other values will be automatically converted to String before being appended, so

```
System.out.println("y = " + first.getSlope() + " x + " + first.getYIntercept());
```

should do the trick.

In future, also say what your error is.